# maximize the groups of combinations to use all values

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of combinations (to a certain sum), I'm struggling to find pairs of unique combinations that use all the numbers from the source.

```
function maximizeGroups(groups, source) {}

const groups = [[10], [1, 3, 6], [1, 9], [3, 7], [4, 6]];
const source = [6, 1, 3, 10, 4, 7, 9]

console.log(maximizeGroups(groups, source)) 
-> expected result [[6, 4], [7, 3], [10], [9, 1]]
```

Here `[1, 3, 6]` is discarded.
Since use of this combination doesn't allow to use the number `4`

Function used:

```
const groups = [[10], [1, 3, 6], [1, 9], [3, 7], [4, 6]];
const source = [6, 1, 3, 10, 4, 7, 9];

function maximizeGroups(groups, source) {
  const sorted = source
    .slice()
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .join('');

  for (let i = 0; i < groups.length - 1; i++) {
    const copy = groups.slice();
    copy.splice(i, 1);
    const check = copy
      .slice()
      .flat()
      .sort((a, b) => a - b)
      .join('');

    if (check === sorted) {
      return copy;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: do you have always data which is possible to solve? what have you tried?

Comment: You're looking for `groups` that contain the same numbers as the `source`,  as a whole or "set" - (not 'sum,' which is equivalent to 'add' when numbers are concerned.)

Comment: @NinaScholz There will always be a solution. I've updated the code here But I don't think this is an effective solution though.

Comment: @wahwahwah I don't understand but the gist is : Simply find out all the combination within the `groups` array that allows all the elements of the source be used.

Comment: It's how you're stepping through the logic. Step through the source and try to match, not the other way around

Comment: @wahwahwah could you please elaborate that?

Comment: for each item in `source` -> does it match something from `group`

Comment: `[1, 3, 6]` also match in the source array, but that shouldn't be in the solution. How do you reckon we go on checking?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234129/discussion-between-wahwahwah-and-prateek-thapa).

Comment: Yes, your solution will definitely not always work.  Even if you reordered the original array it will sometimes fail.  But how do you know that there is always a solution?  Is this a homework problem?  If not, what gives you the guarantee that there is a solution?

Comment: @wahwahwah The problem at it core was to generate a subsets of sum of a certain target within an array. My first initial approach was to brute force all the possible combinations and maximize them. I was stuck on maximizing the groups, thus the above problem. But upon thinking again, I change the code to brute the way to find the combinations. The solution I did come up with -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-imv4ze

Comment: @ScottSauyet Up ^

Comment: @NinaScholz Up^

Comment: Several points: (1) The code you supplied seems to be solving a different problem than what you mentioned here.  (The groups from above are not part of the input at all.)  (2) It's considered perfectly legitimate to answer your own question here.  It would be good for posterity to create an answer with your code (in a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992).) (3) Your use of `filter` seems very much a misuse.  There's probably a more semantic way to do that.  (4) I haven't looked carefully yet, but I look forward to spending a little more time with this code.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Yes, it is actually. In my first approach, I was using brute force to find all the combinations to a certain sum (target) and maximizing the group. Now, rather than finding all the combinations, I just brute force till I find if all the numbers are used or not. About the filter here, could find another better way of doing that. Do realize, the code I wrote in the sandbox has constraints embedded to them, and I have also written the constraints there. Thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: After we generate the sets, this reduces to the set cover problem which is np-complete.  So I don't think that there is an efficient solution.  But I can probably come up with a better approach than you have so far.

Comment: @btilly Do read my previous comments. I've changed the solution and also please go through this -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-imv4ze. I would really like to have the more efficient solution than mine. That would be great.

Comment: @PrateekThapa I posted an answer.  Please let me know whether performance is acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what should be a more efficient solution.  Basically as I'm piecing together the groupings I'm making sure that I'm only considering groups that could wind up summing to the target.

If you have a large number of groups, and there is no solution, this could fail in exponential time.  But normally it will finish fairly quickly.

```
// Helper functions to extract the parts of a "pos:value" pair.
function pairToPos (pair) {
    return Number(pair.split(":")[0]);
}

function pairToValue (pair) {
    return Number(pair.split(":")[1]);
}

function sum (nums) {
    let total = 0;
    nums.forEach( (value) => {total += value} );
    return total;
}

function recursiveSolution(nums, target, maxGroups, sumLookup, pos, partialAnswers) {
    if (pos == nums.length) {
        return partialAnswers;
    }

    // Try starting a new group.
    if ((partialAnswers.length < maxGroups)
      && ([pos, target].join(":") in sumLookup)) {
        // Try adding a new group.
        partialAnswers.push([nums[pos]]);
        let attempt = recursiveSolution(nums, target, maxGroups, sumLookup, pos+1, partialAnswers);
        if (attempt != null) {
            return partialAnswers;
        }
        // Get rid of my new group.
        partialAnswers.pop();
    }

    // Try adding this value to each group.
    let finalAnswers = null;
    partialAnswers.forEach( (group) => {
        if (finalAnswers != null) {
            // Do nothing, we have the answer.
        }
        else if ([pos, target - sum(group)].join(":") in sumLookup) {
            // Try adding this value.
            group.push(nums[pos]);
            let attempt = recursiveSolution(nums, target, maxGroups, sumLookup, pos+1, partialAnswers);
            if (attempt != null) {
                finalAnswers = partialAnswers;
            }
            else {
                // Get rid of my new value.
                group.pop();
            }
        }
    });

    return finalAnswers;
}

function deriveGroups(nums, target) {
    // Use dynamic programming to find all paths to the target.
    let sumLookup = {};
    // We constantly use "pos:value" pairs as keys.
    // This entry means "the empty sum off the array is 0".
    sumLookup[[nums.length, 0].join(":")] = null;

    // We go backwards here to get the future sum from current value + pos.
    for (let i = nums.length-1; 0 <= i; i--) {
        let term = nums[i];
        Object.keys(sumLookup).forEach( (pair) => {
            let prevPos = pairToPos(pair);
            let prevValue = pairToValue(pair);
            let nextPair = [i, prevValue + term].join(":");
            if (! (nextPair in sumLookup)) {
                sumLookup[nextPair] = [];
            }
            sumLookup[nextPair].push(prevPos);
        });
    }

    return recursiveSolution(nums, target, sum(nums)/target, sumLookup, 0, []);
}

console.log(deriveGroups([9, 2, 13, 10, 2, 3], 13));
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, man. 
But the performance drops drastically. In my proposed solution, for cases `deriveGroups([1, 1, 12, 6, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 9, 4], 13)`, it takes ~0.294ms, but your proposed solution takes ~1.5ms.  Is there anything wrong with my solution though? 
I hope you checked -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/javascript-imv4ze

Comment: @PrateekThapa: Without looking carefully at the solution, I know nothing about the performance.  But if this is the normal size of your data, it's hard to imagine that performance make a big difference unless you're running this in a tight loop.  And if your data is typically much larger, then you need to run tests like that, because many algorithms only show performance benefits at larger scales.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I appreciate the time and effort you took for the solution.

Comment: Well, I didn't post anything I came up with, as by the time I understood the requirements, you seemed to have solved it to your own satisfaction.  But the one who posted this answer seemed to invest some time in it.

Comment: My bad. Yeah! it is a difficult problem. I've been engaged with this problem for a while though. @btilly did take some time for it. He did claim that he would come up with an answer much more efficiently than mine. Maybe he has. I'll wait and see. That would be even more exciting.

Comment: As far as performance goes, it does matter in my case. This algorithm runs on a loop with different targets until it finds one or bails out.